# MutableLiveData with BindingAdapter not updating visibility of view

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-livedata

My BindingAdapter only runs once even though I update my LiveData multiple times.

```
public class ButtonViewBindingAdapter
{
    @BindingAdapter("hideIfZero")
    public static void setHideIfZero(View view, MutableLiveData<Integer> currentPosition)
    {
        view.setVisibility(currentPosition.getValue() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.package.PermissionsViewModel"/>

        <variable
            name="clickHandler"
            type="com.package.PermissionsActivity.ClickHandler"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="@{() -> clickHandler.nextSlide()}"
            android:text="@string/intro_next"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="@{() -> clickHandler.previousSlide()}"
            android:text="@string/intro_back"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:hideIfZero="@{viewModel.currentSlidePosition}"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

```
public class PermissionsViewModel extends ViewModel
{
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> currentSlidePosition = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public PermissionsViewModel()
    {
        currentSlidePosition.setValue(0);
    }

    public void setCurrentSlidePosition(final int position)
    {
        currentSlidePosition.setValue(position);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> getCurrentSlidePosition()
    {
        return currentSlidePosition;
    }
}
```

When I update the value in my viewmodel the visibility does still not change. The BindingAdapter does not run more than once. What am I missing here? I want it to hide when the position is 0 otherwise it should show.

Comment: Did you call `setLifecycleOwner()` on your binding object?

Comment: I thought I did but it looks like I only did for the view pagers children. I added it to the activity's onCreate and it works now. Thanks for the help! Sometimes another pair of eyes really helps.

Comment: If you want to add an answer then I will accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you fail to call `setLifecycleOwner()` on the binding object, data binding still works, but quietly fails to get any updates. IIRC, you get the initial value held in the `LiveData` at the time of binding, but nothing after that.

I just filed [a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132040245) to get data binding to complain more visibly if you fail to call `setLifecycleOwner()`.

Comment: This is NOT stated even in the documentation (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#binding_data)

Comment: nice. In my case, onCreateView's fragment missing to apply viewmodel of databinding to viewmodel of fragment. Such as:
viewDataBinding = FragmentRingtoneBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
            viewmodel = viewModel
        }

Answer (score 11):

Example:

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

this being fragment/activity etc.

Comment: Passing a Fragment as LifecycleOwner is risky, `viewLifecycleOwner` should be used instead ([more info](https://proandroiddev.com/5-common-mistakes-when-using-architecture-components-403e9899f4cb))